# How to manage Loopers and Threads (thread doesn't die anymore!)

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, looper

I created a class extending Thread to retrieve user location through LocationManager in a non-ui thread. I implemented this as a thread because it has to be started on request and do its work just for a limited time. 
By the way, I had to add a Looper object in the thread, to be able to create the handler for the LocationManager (onLocationChanged).

This is the code:

```
public class UserLocationThread extends Thread implements LocationListener {
//...
public void run() {
    try {
        Looper.prepare();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        Looper.loop();
        Looper.myLooper().quit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //...
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    //...
    handler.sendMessage(msg); //this is the handler for communication with father thread
}

//...}
```

I would like the thread to start, receive the user location data (in this case just one time), send the data to the main thread via a message to the handler, and then die. 
The problem is that in my case the thread does not die anymore, once the run method ended (that should be fine, because otherwise onLocationChanged would not receive the new locations).

But in this way, assuming that thread's stop and suspend methods are deprecated, what would be a good way, in this case at least, to make a thread with a looper die?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can explicitly quit from `Looper`'s loop using `Handler`:

```
private Handler mUserLocationHandler = null;
private Handler handler = null;

public class UserLocationThread extends Thread implements LocationListener {    

 public void run() {
    try {
          Looper.prepare();
        mUserLocationHandler = new Handler();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        Looper.loop();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //...
    }
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    //...
    handler.sendMessage(msg); 
    if(mUserLocationHandler != null){
        mUserLocationHandler.getLooper().quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case "handler" is a Handler object passed to this thread from the calling thread, to be used to pass the collected data from one to another. Thus, I cannot call handler.getLooper().quit() because it refers to the activity thread, and not to the userLocationThread. Note that onLocationChanged is inside the new thread, and that Looper is required to let this callback method to be called when the locationManager receives a location.

Comment: Thanks; that does the work. By the way, what's the difference between handler.getLooper().quit() and Looper.myLooper().quit()? I thought they work the same!

Comment: When you call `Looper.myLooper()` you get `Looper` associated with current thread. When you call `handler.getLooper()` you get `Looper` associated with specific `handler`.

Comment: But if the handler is associated with the same thread, the returned Looper should be the same, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, if you create `handler` in the same thread where you call `Looper.myLooper()`, they should be the same.

Comment: But in this case Looper.myLooper().quit() does not work, as handler.getLooper().quit() does instead o_O

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean :) No, in your original code you call `Looper.myLooper().quit()` after you call `Looper.mylooper().loop()`. The `loop()` function does not return unless you call `quit()`. And you call `quit()` **after** `loop()`. So basically, you never reach your `quit()` and end up in infinite `loop()`:)

Answer (score 0):

"I implemented this as a tread because it has to be started on request and do its work just for a limited time."

This sounds like a perfect reason to simply reuse the main looper. There's no need to spawn a new Thread here. If you're doing blocking work (network I/O, etc) in onLocationChanged(), at that point you could spin up an ASyncTask.

Implement LocationListener on your Activity/Service or whatever and let it use the main looper by default.

Spawning a new thread, setting it to loop, and then immediately quitting is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

IntentService is good for do this job.

> IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.

Answer (score 0):

`Looper().quit();` is good, and according to specification:

> Causes the loop() method to terminate without processing any more messages in the message queue.

But, if you have a task that already is under processing, and you want to stop it too,  you can acquire working thread and cause it to interrupt:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    handler.sendMessage(msg); //this is the handler for communication with father thread
    if(mUserLocationHandler != null){
        mUserLocationHandler.getLooper().quit();
        mUserLocationHandler.getLooper().getThread().interrupt(); // <-- here
    }
```

}

This works fine with most IO, and thread locking/waiting.

Answer (score -1):

Extend the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class. It does all the threading and handling for you automatically.

Comment: I don't thinks `AsyncTask` will work in this case as thread has to have `Looper` loop.